# OTA_HotelResRQ Fails with GUARANTEE NOT ACCEPTED

Tags: sabre

We have a reservation failing with "GUARANTEE NOT ACCEPTED" in the OTA_HotelResRQ response. The RoomRate node does indeed say GuaranteeSurchargeRequired = "D". So we pass "GDPST". All other reservations in our system appear to flow just fine by either passing GC for "G" and GDPST for "D". For this particular hotel, GDPST is listed asa deposit type in HotelPropertyDescriptionRS. Sabre, very confusing as always.

The odd thing is we do get a Success node back, but there is no confirmation number from the hotel, which is generally found at OTA_HotelResRS.Hotel.BasicPropertyInfo.ConfirmationNumber. We also see a Status of "UC" in the Success node, but I am unsure what that means. Perhaps "unconfirmed?"

**OTA_HotelResRQ & OTA_HotelResRS:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <MessageHeader xmlns="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
         <From>
            <PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">REDACTED</PartyId>
         </From>
         <To>
            <PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">Sabre webservices.havail.sabre.com</PartyId>
         </To>
         <CPAId>REDACTED</CPAId>
         <ConversationId>1540952619</ConversationId>
         <Service type="sabreXML">OTA_HotelResLLSRQ</Service>
         <Action>OTA_HotelResLLSRQ</Action>
         <MessageData>
            <MessageId>1540952619</MessageId>
            <Timestamp>2018-10-30T20:23:39</Timestamp>
            <TimeToLive>2018-10-30T21:23:39</TimeToLive>
         </MessageData>
      </MessageHeader>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility">
         <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">REDACTED</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <OTA_HotelResRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ReturnHostCommand="true" TimeStamp="2015-05-12T02:00:26-06:00" Version="2.1.0">
         <Hotel>
            <BasicPropertyInfo InsertAfter="0" RPH="002" />
            <Guarantee Type="GDPST">
               <CC_Info>
                  <PaymentCard Code="VI" ExpireDate="2021-10" Number="****1111" />
                  <PersonName>
                     <Surname>Fubar</Surname>
                  </PersonName>
               </CC_Info>
            </Guarantee>
            <RoomType NumberOfUnits="1" />
         </Hotel>
      </OTA_HotelResRQ>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <Header>
      <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" mustUnderstand="1">
         <eb:From>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">Sabre webservices.havail.sabre.com</eb:PartyId>
         </eb:From>
         <eb:To>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">REDACTED</eb:PartyId>
         </eb:To>
         <eb:CPAId>REDACTED</eb:CPAId>
         <eb:ConversationId>1540952619</eb:ConversationId>
         <eb:Service>OTA_HotelResLLSRQ</eb:Service>
         <eb:Action>OTA_HotelResLLSRS</eb:Action>
         <eb:MessageData>
            <eb:MessageId>959157086198330212</eb:MessageId>
            <eb:Timestamp>2018-10-31T02:23:41</eb:Timestamp>
            <eb:RefToMessageId>1540952619</eb:RefToMessageId>
         </eb:MessageData>
      </eb:MessageHeader>
      <Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
         <BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/RESB!ICESMSLB\/RES.LB!1540951687295!355929!327681</BinarySecurityToken>
      </Security>
   </Header>
   <Body>
      <OTA_HotelResRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.1.0">
         <ApplicationResults status="Complete">
            <Success timeStamp="2018-10-30T21:23:41-05:00">
               <SystemSpecificResults>
                  <HostCommand LNIATA="222222">/0/0H1½Ú002/GDPSTVI****1111EXP 10 21-FUBAR</HostCommand>
               </SystemSpecificResults>
            </Success>
         </ApplicationResults>
         <Hotel NumberInParty="2" NumberOfUnits="1" SegmentNumber="1" Status="UC">
            <BasicPropertyInfo ChainCode="PF" HotelCityCode="YVR" HotelCode="9976" HotelName="REDACTED" />
            <Guarantee>DPSTVIXXXXXXXXXXXX1111EXP 10 21-FUBAR</Guarantee>
            <POS>
               <Source>
                  <RequestorID>46796444</RequestorID>
               </Source>
            </POS>
            <RoomRates>
               <RoomRate>
                  <AdditionalInfo>
                     <CancelPolicy Option="CNOR" />
                  </AdditionalInfo>
                  <Rates>
                     <Rate Amount="239.00" CurrencyCode="CAD" DCS_AuxRateCode="D1KSP6">
                        <HotelTotalPricing Amount="561.66">
                           <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
                           <TotalSurcharges Amount="0.00" />
                           <TotalTaxes Amount="83.66">
                              <TaxFieldOne>53.26</TaxFieldOne>
                              <TaxFieldThree>24.20</TaxFieldThree>
                              <TaxFieldTwo>6.20</TaxFieldTwo>
                              <Text>BED TAX</Text>
                              <Text>MISCELLANEOUS FEE</Text>
                              <Text>FEDERAL TAX</Text>
                           </TotalTaxes>
                        </HotelTotalPricing>
                     </Rate>
                  </Rates>
               </RoomRate>
            </RoomRates>
            <Text>GUARANTEE NOT ACCEPTED</Text>
            <TimeSpan Duration="2" End="11-18" Start="11-16" />
         </Hotel>
      </OTA_HotelResRS>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

**RoomRate from HotelPropertyDescriptionRS:**

```
<RoomRate DirectConnect="false" GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="D" GuaranteedRateProgram="false" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" IATA_CharacteristicIdentification="D1KSP6" IATA_ProductIdentification="FALL PROMOTIONAL RATE." LowInventoryThreshold="false" RPH="002" RateChangeInd="false" RateConversionInd="false" SpecialOffer="false">
  <AdditionalInfo>
     <CancelPolicy Numeric="00" Option="N">
        <Text>RESERVATION CANNOT BE CANCELED</Text>
     </CancelPolicy>
     <Commission NonCommission="false">10.00 PERCENT COMMISSION</Commission>
     <Text>DELUXE KING 350 SQ FT  I KING PILLOW TOP BED</Text>
     <Text>INTERNET ACCESS 42 INCH LCD TV CABLE CHANNELS</Text>
  </AdditionalInfo>
  <Rates>
     <Rate Amount="239.00" ChangeIndicator="false" CurrencyCode="CAD" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" PackageIndicator="false" RateConversionInd="false" ReturnOfRateInd="false" RoomOnRequest="false">
        <AdditionalGuestAmounts>
           <AdditionalGuestAmount MaxExtraPersonsAllowed="0" NumAdults="0" NumCribs="0">
              <Charges AdultRollAway="0" Crib="0" ExtraPerson="40.00" />
           </AdditionalGuestAmount>
        </AdditionalGuestAmounts>
        <HotelTotalPricing Amount="561.66">
           <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
           <TotalSurcharges Amount="0.00" />
           <TotalTaxes Amount="83.66" />
        </HotelTotalPricing>
     </Rate>
  </Rates>
</RoomRate>
```

**From HotelRateDescriptionRQ:**

```
<RoomRate DirectConnect="false" GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="D" GuaranteedRateProgram="false" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" IATA_CharacteristicIdentification="D1KSP6" IATA_ProductIdentification="FALL PROMOTIONAL RATE." LowInventoryThreshold="false" RateChangeInd="false" RateConversionInd="false" SpecialOffer="false">
  <AdditionalInfo>
     <CancelPolicy Numeric="00" Option="N">
        <Text>RESERVATION CANNOT BE CANCELED</Text>
     </CancelPolicy>
     <Commission NonCommission="false">TA COMMISSION IS 10 PERCENT</Commission>
     <DCA_Cancellation>
        <Text>NON CANCELLABLE RESERVATION</Text>
     </DCA_Cancellation>
     <DCA_Deposit>
        <Text>A DEPOSIT OF 522.92 BY 30-OCT-18 IS MANDATORY</Text>
     </DCA_Deposit>
     <DCA_Guarantee>
        <Text>MUST GUARANTEE ROOM WITH DEPOSIT,AX,CA,CB,DC,DI,DS,IK,JB,JC,MC,</Text>
     </DCA_Guarantee>
     <DCA_Other>
        <Text>MINIMUM LENGTH OF STAY IS 1 NIGHT</Text>
     </DCA_Other>
     <Text>DELUXE KING 350 SQ FT  I KING PILLOW TOP BED</Text>
     <Text>INTERNET ACCESS 42 INCH LCD TV CABLE CHANNELS</Text>
     <Text>IN-ROOM SAFE- MARBLE BATHROOM- PLUSH BATHROBES</Text>
     <Text>-FULL PRE-PAYMENT IS REQUIRED.-NON CANCELLABLE NON REFUNDABLE</Text>
     <Text>239.00 DAILY RATE STARTING 16NOV FOR 2 NIGHTS</Text>
     <Text>478.00 TOTAL RATE STARTING 16NOV FOR 2 NIGHTS</Text>
  </AdditionalInfo>
  <Rates>
     <Rate Amount="239.00" ChangeIndicator="false" CurrencyCode="CAD" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" PackageIndicator="false" RateConversionInd="false" ReturnOfRateInd="false" RoomOnRequest="false">
        <AdditionalGuestAmounts>
           <AdditionalGuestAmount MaxExtraPersonsAllowed="1" NumAdults="0" NumCribs="0">
              <Charges AdultRollAway="0" Crib="0" ExtraPerson="0.00" />
           </AdditionalGuestAmount>
        </AdditionalGuestAmounts>
        <HotelTotalPricing Amount="561.66">
           <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
           <TotalSurcharges Amount="0.00" />
           <TotalTaxes Amount="83.66">
              <TaxFieldOne>53.26</TaxFieldOne>
              <TaxFieldThree>24.20</TaxFieldThree>
              <TaxFieldTwo>6.20</TaxFieldTwo>
              <Text>BED TAX</Text>
              <Text>MISCELLANEOUS FEE</Text>
              <Text>FEDERAL TAX</Text>
           </TotalTaxes>
        </HotelTotalPricing>
     </Rate>
  </Rates>
</RoomRate>
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to book this with a Visa Card: Code="VI"

Hotel only seems to accept: AX,CA,CB,DC,DI,DS,IK,JB,JC,MC as guarantees

Have you tried a different card?

Comment: Yes, Sabre support pointed this out to us, but we had plenty of failures with MC and AX as well. We tried with the company card which is AX to no avail. Unfortunately after pointing that out to them we haven't had any response in days.

Comment: That behaviour is classic Sabre btw - did you get the exact same response when trying with AX? could you post your response?

Comment: Sabre support asked that we remove the InsertAfter attribute from OTA_HotelResRQ. We were able to process both Visa and Amex. I personally just think Sabre is deciding to have a good day. I hate this thing.

Answer (score 0):

UC definitely means "Unconfirmed" and in the UC state the reservation will not be honored at the property (it might not even get transmitted via Sabre, but I'm not sure about that).

Thomas' answer about the accepted forms of payment seems correct to me. Unfortunate that Sabre doesn't return a more clear error response but that's not a surprise.